# Jquery to check an element display status and then hide it

Tags: jquery, html, css, hide, show

I have an element `<p id="message" class="hidden">...</p>`

My CSS:

```
.hidden{
   display:none;
}
.show{
   display:block;
}
```

**Question :** I need help to in JQUERY to check whether the element is hidden or shown. If its shown, hide it(possibly fadeout) after 2 seconds. I need help in checking the element's class whether its active or not. I have no idea how to proceed

**Current JQuery:**

```
$(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#message").hide('blind', {}, 500)
        }, 2000);
    });
```

Comment: why do you need to check?  you just want to hide it no matter what if I understand you correctly..  Or did you want to do something if it's hidden already?

Comment: if its hidden already dont disturb it, only if its shown, hide it after 2 seconds

Comment: so really all you need is `$("#message").delay(2000).fadeOut('slow');` - as this will just hide them all - if it's already hidden nothing will happen - plus this your selector is an ID so there can only be one of those elements

Comment: But your CSS makes it `display: none`, or do you modify the classes at some point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$('#message:visible').delay(2000).hide('fade');
```

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/CxL5W/1

Comment: am sorry. I dont understand? This `#message:visible` checks whether the element is visible or what? I might better understand with a fiddle

Comment: It hides `<p id="message">` when it is visible

Comment: You could target elements of the `show` class, `$('#message.show').delay(2000).hide('fade');`

Comment: @alan, OP is asking for visible or not. I know what you are saying.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if an element is visible using the following

```
$(element).is(":visible")
```

Taken from https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Elements with `visibility: hidden` or `opacity: 0` are considered visible, since they still consume space in the layout.

You could do something like the following

```
if($("#message").is(":visible"))
{
    $("#message").delay(2000).fadeOut();
}
```

Comment: this might sound stupid, but does this statement check the visibility property or the display property?

Comment: @user3291391 I've added a link and an explanation of what constitutes as visible

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.hasClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) to check if it has .hidden or .show

Comment: OP is asking for whether the element is visible or not.

Comment: Really? To me it sounds like they "need help in checking the element's class whether its active or not." And they added CSS for the classes. But you can also check for visibility yes.

Comment: Mate, nothing personal against you but here is the question from OP's post. Copied and pasted **I need help to in JQUERY to check whether the element is hidden or shown.**

Comment: But OP also asked for  **I need help in checking the element's class whether its active or not. I have no idea how to proceed**

Answer (score 0):

You can also use 
 `$(".hidden").css("display")` 
 or 
 `$("#message").css("display")`
in an if/else statement to check wether the object is already visible or not
see [css method - jquery API](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Comment: You can also check out the way to not relaunch a timeout over a previously setted timeout function on 1 element in your page. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

```
if ($('p').hasClass('hidden') == true) { 
//Script if it's hidden
}
else {
//Script if it's visible
}
```

Or

```
if ($('p').css('display') == 'block') {
//Script if it's visible
}
else {
//Script if it's hidden
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if an element has a class is as simple as `$(selector).hasClass('yourClass');`

Ive adjusted your code with a `setInterval`so you clearly see how hasClass works.

```
var $message = $('#message');

setInterval(function() {
  if($message.hasClass('show')) {
      $message.removeClass('show');
      $message.fadeOut('slow',function() {
          $message.addClass('hide');
      });
  } else {
      $message.removeClass('hide');
      $message.fadeIn('slow',function() {
          $message.addClass('show');   
      });
  }
}, 2000);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TnZLP/)

Answer (score 0):

You can check visibility like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($('#myDiv').is(":visible"))
    {
        //visible do some than
    }
    else
    {
        //not visible do some else
    }
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4Awxx/1/)**

Comment: i hate it when my "short post" takes me so long that when i post it already 5 answers are given :)